# Android calling two functions in a webservices

Tags: java, android, json

In my android application I need to call two functions in a web service. I need to display both the values in one page. When I did for one function it was working fine.. but when I tried for second it is not working.. I am giving my code below.

```
class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(R_Details.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Verifying the details... Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


            url = "https://xxx.xxxx.com/appservice/d_service.asmx/mDetails?";
            url2 = "https://xxx.xxxx.com/appservice/d_service.asmx/mGoDetails?";


            SharedPreferences plnumber = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences login        = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);


            pl             = String.valueOf(pnumber.getString("pl","not found"));
            cd            = String.valueOf(login.getString("cid","not found"));
            ud  = String.valueOf(login.getString("uid","not found"));

             List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pl", pl));       
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cd", cd));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ud", ud));

                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += paramString;
                url2 += paramString;

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONPars jPars     = new JSONPars();

            // getting JSON string from URL         
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);  
            JSONObject json2 = jPars.getJSONFromUrl(url2);


                try {

                    final String st       = json.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                    final String po     = json.getString(TAG_PNO);
                    final String pt    = json.getString(TAG_PAMT);
                    final String te   = json.getString(TAG_TRAD);
                    final String me    = json.getString(TAG_MD);
                    final String le   = json.getString(TAG_LTE);

                    final String ph       = json2.getString(TAG_PE);
                    final String pi       = json2.getString(TAG_PE);
                    final String ir        = json2.getString(TAG_IT);
                    final String rt        = json2.getString(TAG_RE);
                    final String tt       = json2.getString(TAG_TNT);


                    de     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dd);
                    lt      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ltd);
                    le    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lted);
                    me = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mad);
                    at      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
                    lo    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvr);

                    pe          = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pd);
                    it           = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
                    pe        = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pd);
                    re             = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rd);
                    tt      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.td);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
                        @Override
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            de.setText(trnsdate);
                            lt.setText(pledamt);
                            le.setText(ltradate);
                            me.setText(matdate);
                            at.setText(stat);
                            lo.setText(pledno);

                            pe.setText(pi);
                            it.setText(ir);
                            pe.setText(ph);
                            re.setText(rt);
                            tt.setText(tt);


                        }
                    });








                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            return null;

        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        }
```

Comment: Not working means any crash?

Comment: I add one answer try that. Still crashing let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is issues in your code.
 Move the following code to `onPostExecute` method

```
de     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dd);
                    lt      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ltd);
                    le    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lted);
                    me = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mad);
                    at      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
                    lo    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvr);

                    pe          = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pd);
                    it           = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
                    pe        = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pd);
                    re             = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rd);
                    tt      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.td);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
                        @Override
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            de.setText(trnsdate);
                            lt.setText(pledamt);
                            le.setText(ltradate);
                            me.setText(matdate);
                            at.setText(stat);
                            lo.setText(pledno);

                            pe.setText(pi);
                            it.setText(ir);
                            pe.setText(ph);
                            re.setText(rt);
                            tt.setText(tt);


                        }
                    });
```

Reason: Don't use UI widgets in `doInBackGround` method

Comment: but it was working fine for one url... when I added the url2 it began crashing

Comment: Post your logcat that will help. I told this only based on guess. Don't know your exact erroer